# Como "fixar" Copyright?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Olá! Estou com uma dúvida que eu não consegui encontrar em nenhum site, ou eu não usei as palavras corretas para encontrar.

Tem um site de templates que obviamente disponibiliza templates, porém quando o cara remove os créditos, ao acessar o meu blog por exemplo, é redirecionado automáticamente para o site do cara que disponibiliza templates.

Eu sei como remover, porém eu queria aprender a fazer isso.

Alguém poderia ajudar por favor?

**Exemplos:**

Aqui está os créditos:

```html
<div class='footbawahkanan'>
Designed by <span id='lightcredits'><a href='http://www.arlinadzgn.com/' target='_blank' title='Kreativitas adalah kunci kesuksesan'>Arlina Design</a></span> Powered by <a href='https://www.blogger.com/' rel='nofollow' target='_blank' title='Powered by Blogger'>Blogger</a>
</div>
```

Quando alguém altera o nome ou remove, o blog é redicionado para o site da Arlina Design.

Aí eu acabei que encontrando o código que faz com que seja redicionado, que no caso são esses dois:

```js
$(document)[_0xa908[12]](function(){var _0x5fbex1=90;$(_0xa908[11])[_0xa908[10]](_0xa908[9])[_0xa908[8]](function(_0x5fbex2,_0x5fbex3){var _0x5fbex3=$(_0x5fbex3);_0x5fbex3[_0xa908[3]]({src:_0x5fbex3[_0xa908[3]](_0xa908[2])[_0xa908[1]](/s\B\d{2,4}/,_0xa908[0]+ _0x5fbex1)}),_0x5fbex3[_0xa908[3]](_0xa908[4],_0xa908[5]),_0x5fbex3[_0xa908[3]](_0xa908[6],_0xa908[7])})});var mql=window[_0xa908[14]](_0xa908[13]);mql[_0xa908[15]]&& (window[_0xa908[16]]= function(){var _0x5fbex5=document[_0xa908[18]](_0xa908[17]);null== _0x5fbex5&& (window[_0xa908[20]][_0xa908[19]]= _0xa908[21]),_0x5fbex5[_0xa908[22]](_0xa908[19],_0xa908[21]),_0x5fbex5[_0xa908[22]](_0xa908[23],_0xa908[24]),_0x5fbex5[_0xa908[25]]= _0xa908[26]})
```

**e esse:**

```js
var _0x602a=["\x73\x63\x72\x65\x65\x6E\x20\x61\x6E\x64\x20\x28\x6D\x69\x6E\x2D\x77\x69\x64\x74\x68\x3A\x20\x36\x30\x65\x6D\x29","\x6D\x61\x74\x63\x68\x4D\x65\x64\x69\x61","\x6D\x61\x74\x63\x68\x65\x73","\x6F\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64","\x6C\x69\x67\x68\x74\x63\x72\x65\x64\x69\x74\x73","\x67\x65\x74\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x42\x79\x49\x64","\x68\x72\x65\x66","\x6C\x6F\x63\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E","\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x77\x77\x77\x2E\x61\x72\x6C\x69\x6E\x61\x64\x7A\x67\x6E\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D","\x73\x65\x74\x41\x74\x74\x72\x69\x62\x75\x74\x65","\x72\x65\x6C","\x6E\x6F\x66\x6F\x6C\x6C\x6F\x77","\x69\x6E\x6E\x65\x72\x48\x54\x4D\x4C","\x3C\x61\x20\x68\x72\x65\x66\x3D\x27\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x77\x77\x77\x2E\x61\x72\x6C\x69\x6E\x61\x64\x7A\x67\x6E\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D\x2F\x27\x20\x74\x61\x72\x67\x65\x74\x3D\x27\x5F\x62\x6C\x61\x6E\x6B\x27\x20\x74\x69\x74\x6C\x65\x3D\x27\x4B\x72\x65\x61\x74\x69\x76\x69\x74\x61\x73\x20\x61\x64\x61\x6C\x61\x68\x20\x6B\x75\x6E\x63\x69\x20\x6B\x65\x73\x75\x6B\x73\x65\x73\x61\x6E\x27\x3E\x41\x72\x6C\x69\x6E\x61\x20\x44\x65\x73\x69\x67\x6E\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E"];var mql=window[_0x602a[1]](_0x602a[0]);mql[_0x602a[2]]&& (window[_0x602a[3]]= function(){var _0x2a73x2=document[_0x602a[5]](_0x602a[4]);null== _0x2a73x2&& (window[_0x602a[7]][_0x602a[6]]= _0x602a[8]),_0x2a73x2[_0x602a[9]](_0x602a[6],_0x602a[8]),_0x2a73x2[_0x602a[9]](_0x602a[10],_0x602a[11]),_0x2a73x2[_0x602a[12]]= _0x602a[13]})
```

Quando eu removo essas duas linhas com esses códigos, eu teno total liberdade de modificar os créditos do autor.

Só que eu queria saber como faço isso, adiciono meus créditos e caso alguém remova, o blog dele(a) será redicionado para o meu blog.

Espero que tenham entendido.

Comment: Já pesquisou algo como "javascript obfuscator"? Olá esse link como exemplo: http://www.addressmunger.com/javascript_obfuscator/index.php

Comment: Certo, mas como funciona? eu li mas eu até tentei fazer, só que não consegui. Você sabe como?